# assign events to cloned html block

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i am using Jquery 1.3

i have a html block in which there are many tags like input , button , hyperlink etc.

now whenever i clone this block of html its events don't get copied automatically as clone() only copies html block , so i wan to know that how to assign events to cloned html block ?

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/clone/ from this documentation, just use (true) when you call the clone method.

Comment: well true is to copy only child elements , not their values

Comment: "withDataAndEvents A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements." This is per 1.0, in 1.4 it copies data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try jquery [live() method](http://api.jquery.com/live/). It was mentioned in answer to similar question on SO, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: live () method is not available in jquery 1.3

Comment: In the docs I saw: ".live( eventType, handler ) version added: 1.3" - but I didn't test it, so it can be not available after all.

Comment: `live()` most certainly is available in jQuery 1.3.  Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/live/  It works just fine in 1.3.2 with minor limitations.

Comment: m sorry live handler is there , but i am using blur event and in jquery 1.3 live('blur',function(){})  is not supported